# TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new' when I tried to use in a button with router v5

Tags: reactjs

Hi Guys I got this error when I do click on the Gameboardbutton:

**TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'**

```
export default class Onclickredirectrouter extends Component {
    static get contextTypes() {
      return {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
      };
    }
    handleClick() {
      this.context.router.push('/');
    }
  }
  
  export const Gameboardbutton = () => (
    <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        onClick={Onclickredirectrouter}>
      Gameboardbutton
    </button>
  );
```

I am using: @testing-library/react@11.2.7 , react-dom@17.0.2, react-dom@17.0.2
I read some posts that look at some settings in package.json.
Any guide or ideas?

Comment: Why have you created a different component only for routing. Why not use the function directly.

Comment: You're passing a class component as a prop to the `onClick`, you need to pass the handleClick if you want it to work this way.

As @TusharShahi mentioned, this is an anti-pattern, just use the the function directly, you don't need to wrap it in a class.

Comment: I changed to export default class Onclickredirectrouter extends Router and gave the same error.

Comment: @BojanIvanac thank you I will check

Comment: @TusharShahi thank you I will check

Answer (score 0):

why don't you upgrade to `React-router-dom v6` ?
You can simply achieve that using `Navigate`, check docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#navigation)

you just import it

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
let navigate = useNavigate();
```

and in your `onClick` of your button, you call `navigate()` function with the desired destination

```
onClick={()=>navigate('/')}
```

Comment: So great idea , pls let me try .

Comment: @grojas123 sure, keep me updated ^^

Answer (score 0):

With Router 6 works so nice . Thank you @mohamed-salah
This is the final code for your reference :

```
let navigate = useNavigate();
   function Handleclick(gameid) {
     let path="/chatboard/" + gameid;
     navigate(path)
     }
    
  const Gameboardbutton = () => (
      <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
          onClick={() => Handleclick({game_id_temp})}>
        Gameboardbutton
      </button>
    );
```